# Can I start a chat with a specific user?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

Sometimes I find questions or answers by users and I would like to ask the user a specific question that doesn't (yet) fit as a full SO question.

Adding a comment with @username doesn't necessarily seem appropriate, as it isn't a comment on the question or answer per se.

So, can I somehow open a chat or contact that user without putting in a comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is allowed to start a chatroom with a user, but they are under no obligation to enter it with you and actually talk to you.

You can either request them to join by leaving a comment on their post with a link to the chatroom, or visiting their Profile on https://chat.stackoverflow.com and clicking the `Start a new room with this user` button. This only works if they've already been on chat before, and if you do this they will automatically be given a notification that they have been invited to join a room on chat.

It is entirely up to the user to join in either of these cases and you cannot force them.

Comment: Excellent. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users - start chat was what I was looking for!